# Google Maps api v3 blank page, adding api didnt solve it

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, api-key

I have a Wordpress theme. It has a map with locations. It worked fined, but suddenly today the map showed an error for too many requests. After some research i added an api browser key to avoid getting over the limit of requests. But after i added my browser key my map is still blank. The error messages i got earlier are solved but the map still isn't showing.

Here is the link of a page which shows a blank map: http://goodgoal.org/review-category/eating-and-drinking/

These are the api's enabled on my developer console:
[image]

EDIT: a big problem is the performance, which i am working on. But an issue still persists. In safari & firefox the map is showing correctly, in chrome the map is still blank. I tried the css solution but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you using any plugins for this?

Comment: the theme is called listify and it uses the wp job manager plugin.

Comment: The map is displaying for me (on Chrome), it just take 2min+ to load. Server took 45sec to serve a single PNG file, so it seems your server is a bit overloaded. You should consider working on reducing your page size, with the media the page is 10.7MB sized, which is just huge.

Comment: The size is idd a problem, but i have the page open for a solid 5-6 min now without reloading and the map is still not showing, i'm also on chrome.

Comment: @vard is right, it took 2.9 min for me to load [this image](http://goodgoal.org/wp-content/uploads/Biokeller.png).

Comment: The loading is an issue my client has uploaded a lot of large images. But what i don't understand is why its inconsistent? I see the map in safari & in firefox, but it doesnt show in chrome, not even in incognito modus . I asked multiple people and they all get different results ? that problem is not realted to the loading time is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured that there is a css problem on your map. The `max-width: 100%` property on all images break the width (and then height) calculation of the images that form your map.

If you try to add the following rule :

```css
.job_listings-map-wrapper #job_listings-map-canvas img {
  max-width: none;
}
```

The map will display properly. This is in the case of the map display only the markers but whithout the map behind.

For other inconsistent load issues, the problem is more server related. As I said the page size is way too big, and I guess the server (probably a shared hosting?) isn't really sized for this. Maybe you could try to increase your `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit` settings and see if it helps.

Comment: I will fix the performance, maybe switch to an higher performance package, i tried your css approach but that didn't really change anything. I still have the issue that safari and firefox work but chrome won't.